# Get html from two layout updates on ajax requet

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, layout-update

I'm trying rerender onepage checkout billing and shipping steps on ajax request. I'm trying following code

```
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();
        $response['shipping'] = $output;

        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_paymentmethod');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();
        $response['payment'] = $output; // second output same as first one
```

But both outputs are same.
How can I get output from different updates?

Comment: Can you add more details? Please add code about how to you send and receive response for your Ajax request.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya never mind. I've already solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found issue. On update load it use cache from previous load. So I've solve it with remove cache before update load.

```
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        Mage::app()->removeCache($update->getCacheId()); // fix the issue
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_progress_shipping_method');
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();
        $response['shipping'] = $output;

        Mage::app()->removeCache($update->getCacheId()); // fix the issue
        $update->load('checkout_onepage_paymentmethod'); 
        $layout->generateXml();
        $layout->generateBlocks();
        $output = $layout->getOutput();
        $response['payment'] = $output;
```